# How to interact with a hidden element (toggle/checkbox)?

Tags: automated-tests, playwright, playwright-typescript

I am trying to click an input html element with attribute type="checkbox". However it seems to be hidden. How can I get around this?

I initially tried interacting with it using the .setChecked() and unCheck() functions. When that didn't work I tried using javascript with the following line:

```js
await this.page.evaluate(`document.querySelector('selector').click()`);
```

This also does not work, in the console I can see this returns `undefined`. Also, when debugging in the console I noticed that running:

```js
document.querySelector('selector').checkVisibility();
```

returns `false`

Comment: Do you just want to change its `checked` state, or trigger a `click` event listener?

Comment: Also, `click()` is supposed to return `undefined`, if you want the checkbox's value, read its `checked` property

Comment: I want to change it's `checked` state @DustInComp

Comment: If you're doing an automated test, there shouldn't be a reason to try to click a hidden element, but if you have to, there are [several workarounds](https://playwright.dev/docs/input#forcing-the-click) described in the documentation.

Comment: It's a bit hard to say without a runnable [mcve] that includes the page. Behavior can be complex and arbitrary on sites, so telling you how to scrape them blindly is a difficult order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you'd want to identify the checkbox using one of the more modern forms of locator and then force the check to take place regardless of the actionability checks that would usually be required:

```
await page.getByRole('checkbox').setChecked(true, {force: true});
```

or

```
await page.getByLabel('Checkbox label').check({force: true});
```

You can use either method, setChecked or check, they both accept "force".